# simulator required for Siemens S7-200

Tags: plc

I need a simulator for Siemens S7-200, which operates without communication of Programmable Logic Controller with PC.And it is download able version not online version. 
Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LibNoDave](http://libnodave.sourceforge.net)** had a server example where you could simulate DB and IO so that clients think that they talk to real PLC. It was working for S7 300 and S7 400, so you might check if it works for S7 200 (since library supports all of them). However you can not run your PLC application with it. If you need that then you would have to try to replicate PLC behaviour with custom PC code.